# Find unwanted files in a directory path by batch file?

Tags: file, batch-file

I have some hex files in a directory

```
autoplay.hex
process.hex
```

The user maybe add another hex file to this directory. I want to write a batch file that find the the name of the added file and save the name in a variable. The user may add only one file to the directory.

Comment: You might be able to use `dir /q filename.ext > X:\path\filename.whocreated.txt`. (`/q` will show the owner). It will output more than just the owner, but at least the information will be in there.

Comment: @PeterB sorry i edited the question . I want to know the name of the file

Comment: The question is unclear. What do you want to put in the variable? Just the file name? How do you distinguish an "added" file from an existing file?

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "wanted=autoplay.hex process.hex"

for %%a in (*.hex) do (
   if "!wanted:%%a=!" equ "%wanted%" set "unwanted=%%a"
)
echo %unwanted%
```

**EDIT**: *Some explanations added*

The `if` command basically ask if the current file name is *not* in the wanted list, because in such a case the wanted list would change (when the existent name is deleted from it). So in this case (when the wanted list don't change, that means that the filename is not there), get the name of the unwanted file...

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help. A proper explanation [would greatly improve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions. Please edit your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton: Done! May I ask for an upvote after that? **`;)`**

Comment: Certainly. I will do an upvote tomorrow because I've hit my limit for the day. :)